# How can i check whether the current time in between tonight 9pm and 9am(tomorrow) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datetime

I need to check whether my current times is between the specified time interval (tonight 9pm and 9am tomorrow). How can this be done in Ruby on Rails.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Obviously this is an old question, already marked with a *correct* answer, however, I wanted to post an answer that might help people finding the same question via search.

The problem with the answer marked correct is that your current time may be past midnight, and at that point in time, the proposed solution will fail.

Here's an alternative which takes this situation into account.

```
now = Time.now

if (0..8).cover? now.hour 
# Note: you could test for 9:00:00.000 
#       but we're testing for BEFORE 9am.
#       ie. 8:59:59.999
  a = now - 1.day
else 
  a = now
end

start = Time.new a.year, a.month, a.day, 21, 0, 0
b = a + 1.day
stop = Time.new b.year, b.month, b.day, 9, 0, 0

puts (start..stop).cover? now
```

Again, use `include?` instead of `cover?` for ruby 1.8.x

<sup>Of course you should upgrade to Ruby 2.0</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Create a Range object having the two Time instances that define the range you want, then use the `#cover?` method (if you are on ruby 1.9.x):

```
now = Time.now
start = Time.gm(2011,1,1)
stop = Time.gm(2011,12,31)

p Range.new(start,stop).cover? now # => true
```

Note that here I used the explicit method constructor just to make clear that we are using a `Range` instance. You could safely use the Kernel constructor `(start..stop)` instead.

If you are still on Ruby 1.8, use the method `Range#include?` instead of `Range#cover?`:

```
p (start..stop).include? now
```

Comment: Why the explicit `Range.new` instead of `(start..stop).cover? now`?

Comment: am getting an error undefined method `cover?' for Sat Jan 01 00:00:00 UTC 2011..Sat Dec 31 00:00:00 UTC 2011:Range
 from (irb):11
 from /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/date.rb:1770

Comment: @AmalKumarS: you are probably on 1.8, `cover?` was introduced in 1.9.

Comment: ohh..I see. am using ruby 1.8

Comment: @MichaelKohl: I edited the answer to explain why I used Range.new

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

today = Date.today
tomorrow = today + 1

nine_pm = Time.local(today.year, today.month, today.day, 21, 0, 0)
nine_am = Time.local(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 9, 0, 0)

(nine_pm..nine_am).include? Time.now #=> false
```

Comment: How did this get marked as correct? If the _current time_ is past midnight, `today + 1` is going to be the following day. You'd need to do an additional check if the current time was between 00:00 and 09:00, and then build your range accordingly.

Comment: I guess it got marked as correct because some people are able to extrapolate what they need from provided examples.

Answer (score 0):

This might read better in several situations and the logic is simpler if you have `18.75` for "18:45"

```
def afterhours?(time = Time.now)
  midnight = time.beginning_of_day
  starts = midnight + start_hours.hours + start_minutes.minutes
  ends = midnight + end_hours.hours + end_minutes.minutes
  ends += 24.hours if ends < starts
  (starts...ends).cover?(time)
end
```

I'm using 3 dots because I don't consider 9:00:00.000am after hours.

Then it's a different topic, but it's worth highlighting that `cover?` comes from `Comparable` (like `time < now`), while `include?` comes from `Enumerable` (like array inclusion), so I prefer to use `cover?` when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I check if an event is tomorrow in Rails 3.x

```
(event > Time.now.tomorrow.beginning_of_day) && (event < Time.now.tomorrow.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 0):

if time is between one day:

(start_hour..end_hour).include? Time.zone.now.hour