# How do I check if a time is between 9am yesterday and 9 am today in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, time

I'm very new to Ruby and I don't understand the answer to [How can i check whether the current time in between tonight 9pm and 9am(tomorrow) in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580734/how-can-i-check-whether-the-current-time-in-between-tonight-9pm-and-9amtomorrow).

I have a time and I want to see if it is between 9am the day before and 9am today - how do I do that?

I've tried using that answer, but I'm not sure if I did it correctly-

```
updated_at = #some time that I access

if (0..8).cover? updated_at.hour 
  a = updated_at - 1.day
else 
  a = updated_at
end

start = Time.new updated_at.year, updated_at.month, updated_at.day, 9, 0, 0
b = a + 1.day
stop = Time.new b.year, b.month, b.day, 9, 0, 0

puts (start..stop).cover? updated_at
```

Comment: The page you linked to answers your question and you haven't told us what about those answers you don't understand, so I'm not sure what you expect us to do here.

Comment: So I tried using that answer, and I'm not sure if I repurposed it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yesterday_at_nine = Time.parse('9:00') - 1.day
today_at_nine = Time.parse('9:00')
now = Time.now

(yesterday_at_nine..today_at_nine).cover? now
```

Answer (score 0):

This will determine if the current time is in between 9pm and 9am:

```
time = Time.now
time.hour > 20 or time.hour < 9
```

For example:

```
time = Time.now
#=> 2016-08-01 20:23:32 +0000
time.hour > 20 or time.hour < 9
#=> false
```